# Spark : Writing data frame to s3 bucket

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write DF data to S3 bucket. It is working fine as expected. Now i want to write to s3 bucket based on condition.

In data frame i am having one column as Flag and in that column values are T and F . Now the condition is If Flag is F then it should write the data to S3 bucket otherwise No. Please find the details below.

DF Data :

```
1015,2017/08,新潟,101,SW,39,1015,2017/08,山形,101,SW,10,29,74.35897435897436,11.0,F
1015,2017/08,新潟,101,SW,39,1015,2017/08,大分,101,SW,14,25,64.1025641025641,15.4,F
1015,2017/08,新潟,101,SW,39,1015,2017/08,山口,101,SW,6,33,84.61538461538461,6.6,T
1015,2017/08,新潟,101,SW,39,1015,2017/08,愛媛,101,SW,5,34,87.17948717948718,5.5,T
1015,2017/08,新潟,101,SW,39,1015,2017/08,神奈川,101,SW,114,75,192.30769230769232,125.4,F
1015,2017/08,新潟,101,SW,39,1015,2017/08,富山,101,SW,12,27,69.23076923076923,13.2,F
1015,2017/08,新潟,101,SW,39,1015,2017/08,高知,101,SW,3,36,92.3076923076923,3.3,T
1015,2017/08,新潟,101,SW,39,1015,2017/08,岩手,101,SW,11,28,71.7948717948718,12.1,F
1015,2017/08,新潟,101,SW,39,1015,2017/08,三重,101,SW,45,6,15.384615384615385,49.5,F
1015,2017/08,新潟,101,SW,39,1015,2017/08,京都,101,SW,23,16,41.02564102564102,25.3,F
1015,2017/08,新潟,101,SW,39,1015,2017/08,静岡,101,SW,32,7,17.94871794871795,35.2,F
1015,2017/08,新潟,101,SW,39,1015,2017/08,鹿児島,101,SW,18,21,53.84615384615385,19.8,F
1015,2017/08,新潟,101,SW,39,1015,2017/08,福島,101,SW,17,22,56.41025641025641,18.7,F
```

Code :

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load("s3a://test_system/transcation.csv")
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
    val res = spark.sql("select count(*) from data")
    res.show(10)
    res.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("header","true").mode("Overwrite")
     .save("s3a://test_system/Output/Test_Result")
     res.createOrReplaceTempView("res1")
     val res2 = spark.sql("select distinct flag from res1 where flag = 'F'")
     if (res2 ==='F')
     {
     //writing to s3 bucket as raw data .Here transcation.csv file.
     df.write.format("csv").option("header","true").mode("Overwrite")
     .save("s3a://test_system/Output/Test_Result/rawdata")
     }
```

I am trying this approach but it is not exporting df data to s3 bucket.
How can i export/write data to S3 bucket by using condition?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: res2 is a data frame and that is what you want to write to S3

Comment: No.I want to write df data based on Flag column condition. I have to put that column condition  Flag ==F then it will write df.write.....otherwise it wont.

Comment: Your res1 table is just a count table which you created at line 3 of your code.

Comment: Are you trying to save only those records which has Flag 'F'  or you're only looking for whether entire dataset contains 'F' value in the Flag ??

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you want to write the dataframe given a "F" flag present in the dataframe.

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load("s3a://test_system/transcation.csv")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
val res = spark.sql("select count(*) from data")
res.show(10)
res.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("header","true").mode("Overwrite")
  .save("s3a://test_system/Output/Test_Result")
res.createOrReplaceTempView("res1")
```

Here we are using the `data` table since `res1` table is just a count table which you created above. Also from the result dataframe, we are selecting just the first row by using `first()` function and the first column from that row using `getAs[String](0)`

```
val res2 = spark.sql("select distinct flag from data where flag = 'F'").first().getAs[String](0)

println("Printing out res2 = " + res2)
```

Here we are doing a comparision between the string extracted above and the string `"F"`. Remember `"F"` is a string while `'F'` is a char in scala.

```
if (res2.equals("F"))
{
  println("Inside the if loop")
  //writing to s3 bucket as raw data .Here transcation.csv file.
  df.write.format("csv").option("header","true").mode("Overwrite")
    .save("s3a://test_system/Output/Test_Result/rawdata")
}
```

Comment: I would avoid the use of overwrite with s3 because it does a query for every write, making it extremely operationally intensive.